# How to make UIButton clickable outside frame of it's grand parent view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a series of buttons that exist outside the frame of its grand parent view. These buttons are not able to be clicked now, and I am not able to move the buttons, so how can I make them clickable outside the frame of the grand parent view? The button exists inside the a small circular UIView, and that UIView lives outside of the frame of it's parent view. I've tried using a hit test but it is still not triggering

Here is my button:

```
class ButtonNode: UIButton {
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
        }
    
        convenience init(frame: CGRect, agree: Bool) {
            self.init(frame: frame)
            setupView()
        }
        
        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
        }
        
        func setupView(){
            self.setTitle("+10", for: .normal)
            self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
            self.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .normal)
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        }
    }
```

This is the setup in the parent view:

```
var rightLastNodeButton:UIButton?
var leftLastNodeButton:UIButton?

leftButton = ButtonNode(frame: CGRect(x: leftX, y: y, width: width, height: height), agree: false)
rightButton = ButtonNode(frame: CGRect(x: rightX, y: y, width: width, height: height), agree: false)
leftButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(disagreeUsers), for: .touchUpInside)
rightButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(agreeUsers), for: .touchUpInside)
                
  view.addSubview(leftButton!)
  view.addSubview(rightButton!)

@objc func agreeUsers(){
        delegate?.showParticipantsPressed(agree: true)

    }
    
    @objc func disagreeUsers(){
        delegate?.showParticipantsPressed(agree: false)

    }

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        
        if(rightButton!.frame.contains(point)) {
            return rightButton
        }
        if(leftButton!.frame.contains(point)){
            return leftButton
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
```

Comment: You need to use hit test

Comment: @RajaKishan check the updated code, hit test wasn't working for  me

Comment: try this inside hitTest method ``` if let hitView = rightButton.hitTest(rightButton.convert(point, from: self), with: event) {
            return hitView
        }```

Comment: @RajaKishan it somewhat works, but is acting strange, the right button will work sometimes it is clicked, but the left will not

Comment: you have to do same for both

Comment: Yup I did, and it's not working

Comment: I tried making the buttons bigger, it still doesn't trigger every time it's tapped. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: @RajaKishan it appears the issue is that hitTest isn't triggering at all. Some of the button is still in the Frame of the parent view so if you click there the button action triggers, but the hitTest is not

Comment: FIrst, if you are using `view.addSubview` it's probably best to remember it's *not* a parent view but a `UIViewController`. (Pet peeve of mine. Yes, both buttons are *in* that VC's root view hierarchy, but this is likely related to your issue.) Second, what's visible *outside* each button? By this I mean that it's outside of said VC, right? And it works on the *visible* part? SO what does the user see instead of the *invisible* part?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and what worked for me was bringing the buttons to the front of the subview. Then it would work.

```
view.bringSubiewToFront(exampleButton)
```

or sending the other subviews back

```
view.sendSubViewToBack(viewlayer)
```